# Swift UITextField icon position set

Tags: swift, uitextfield

Add Icon in UITextField using

```
var leftImageView = UIImageView()
leftImageView.image = leftImage
textField.leftView = leftImageView
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
leftImageView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 15, 20)
textField.addSubview(leftImageView)
```

o/p for this[image: Image is close to textfield border]

I found solution like remove this code from above code

```
textField.leftView = leftImageView
```

It give icon alignment proper but whenever start editing text field text on icon like this [image]

I want o/p like this

[image]

Comment: try this cool library in swift 3.0 https://github.com/Sahilberi/ImageTextField

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely not add the image as a subview to the label. It's enough to set the `leftView` property.

```
textField.addSubview(leftImageView) // Delete this line
```

Secondly, any x or y offsets that you apply to the left view's frame are ignored. The text field will only care about the view's size. If you want to add padding around the image, one option is to use a container view and position the image view inside of it.

```
let leftImageView = UIImageView()
leftImageView.image = leftImage

let leftView = UIView()
leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)

leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)
leftImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 20)

textField.leftView = leftView
```

Another option would be to subclass `UITextField` and override `leftViewRectForBounds`.

Answer (score 4):

Referring @hennes syntax , there are some syntax missing in swift like CGRect syntax is changed and `userNameTextField.leftViewMode = .always` is missing

With swift syntax this worked for me :

```
    let leftImageView = UIImageView()
    leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "email")

    let leftView = UIView()
    leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)

    leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    leftImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
    userNameTextField.leftViewMode = .always
    userNameTextField.leftView = leftView
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. May be help you.

```
var padding: Float = 20

var envelopeView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(padding, 0, 30, 30))
envelopeView.image = UIImage.imageNamed("comment-128.png")
envelopeView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

var viewLeft: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(padding, 0, 30, 30))
viewLeft.addSubview(envelopeView)
textField.leftView.setFrame(envelopeView.frame)
textField.leftView = viewLeft
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways

var viewRight: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(textField.frame.size.width - (textField.frame.size.width + 30 + padding), 0, 30, 30))
viewRight.addSubview(envelopeView)
textField.rightView.setFrame(envelopeView.frame)
textField.rightView = viewRight
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.1

```
extension UITextField
{
    enum Direction
    {
        case Left
        case Right
    }

    func AddImage(direction:Direction,imageName:String,Frame:CGRect,backgroundColor:UIColor)
    {
        let View = UIView(frame: Frame)
        View.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: Frame)
        imageView.contentMode = .center
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        View.addSubview(imageView)

        if Direction.Left == direction
        {
            self.leftViewMode = .always
            self.leftView = View
        }
        else
        {
            self.rightViewMode = .always
            self.rightView = View
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use this @jethava yogesh

Comment: yourtextbox.AddImage(direction:.Left,imageName:"imageName",Frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:40),backgroundColor:UIColor.red)